# Wait for method to finish

Tags: c#

How can I wait for a method to finish using C#?

Comment: Could you explain a bit better what you're trying to achieve please?

Comment: If your application is not multi-threaded and the method you called is not async your next piece of code will be called after the method returns. We need some more information to work with here, are you using threads or `Begin..()` methods?

Comment: Must we assume you're talking about an asynchronous method call?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Unless you're using multiple threads, execution won't continue in the *calling* code until the method has completed anyway.

If you *are* using multiple threads, it really depends on how you're launching the task. For example, you could be using asynchronous delegate execution (`foo.BeginInvoke(...)`) or the Task Parallel Library, or simply creating a new thread. Each approach has its own way of waiting until the task/thread has completed. Please give us more information and we can help you more, but options *may* include:

- Calling `EndInvoke` on the delegate, passing in the `IAsyncResult` returned by `BeginInvoke`
- Calling [`Task.Wait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635.aspx) (optionally with a timeout)
- Calling [`Thread.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx) (optionally with a timeout)

Comment: +1 Sure .. @mdm thats why we have [Jon Skeet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/stack-overflow-is-you) here

Comment: +1 for actually providing options in the case of multithreaded code.

Comment: And, @Pillblast, I guess (but surely will be corrected if I'm wrong) this answer also applies to threads that are automatically created/used for button onclick handlers and such.

Comment: Thank you  so much for your answer. I read about allof them and ended up using the first version

Answer (score 10):

1. Call the method.
2. Wait for it to finish.

**Note**: Only works for blocking calls.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you are asking how to wait for a Code executing on another Thread in your main Thread . For that purpose [**Thread.Join()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx) method will do what you want.

*(A nice tutorial on how to do [Multithreading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).)*

Comment: I know you posted this months ago, but that link to the tutorial just saved my life. I cannot thank you enough for sharing that link.