# wait for one function call would finish c#

Tags: c#, wpf, wait

In my app I have two buttons:

```
void Install_1_Click(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 RunSilentSetup("C:\app1.exe");
}
.
.
.
void Install_2_Click(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 RunSilentSetup("C:\app2.exe");
}
```

and the method that runs the setup:

```
void RunSilentSetup(string executableFilePath)
{
 //code that runs the setup goes here
}
```

The problem: if the user clicks one button and immediately press the second, it throw error that I can't install simultaneously.

My question: I want that the second call to method `RunSilentSetup` will wait intill the first call will finish, how can I achieve that?

**edit installation code:**

```
   try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            startInfo.FileName = executableFilePath;
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.Arguments = "/s /v/qn";
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                int exitcode = exeProcess.ExitCode;

                if (exitcode == 0)
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        ShowMessage(_vm.ShowSuccess , "Installation was successfully completed");
                    });
                else
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        ShowMessage(_vm.ShowError , $"one or more errors occurred during the installation, exit code: {exitcode}");
                    });
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Warn(ex);
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you could disable the second Button until the first call is finished?

Comment: @RTExeption I would consider using the `Exited` event instead. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx . When that event fires, set the button to be like in bommelding's answer below. _If the `Exited` event fires before setup is complete then you have a different issue - which is that you call one setup process and then it shells out to a second process (so the first dies before the second completes). Let us know if that is the case here._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a static `isRunning` type field like this:

```
void Install_1_Click(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RunSilentSetup("C:\app1.exe");
}

void Install_2_Click(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RunSilentSetup("C:\app2.exe");
}

static bool setupIsRunning = false;

void RunSilentSetup(string executableFilePath)
{
    if(setupIsRunning)
        return;

    setupIsRunning = true;
    //disable both buttons
    Install_1.Enabled = false;
    Install_2.Enabled = false;

    //code that runs the setup goes here

    setupIsRunning = false; //set back to false when finished

    //re-enable both buttons
    Install_1.Enabled = true;
    Install_2.Enabled = true;
}
```

There's different ways of doing this, but this is the most simple I can come up with.

Now, when `RunSilentSetup` is called, it fist checks to see if `setupIsRunning` is true. If it is, it will return (without further executing the `RunSilentSetup` method.

If not, it sets `setupIsRunning` to true - to stop subsequent calls.

When finished, `setupIsRunning` is set back to false.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment? Or you just downvoting every answer on here?

Comment: Like in my own answer, you probably won't see the buttons go grey.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable second button until the first button is clicked

(or)

You can also check this link to get any ideas
[Wait for method to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297076/wait-for-method-to-finish)

Comment: How about the first button when the second is clicked? And there are 2 other flows.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, if it's WPF, create a `bool IsWorking` then convert it to the button enabled property via binding converter, then you have your problem solved ^^

Comment: This was my (expanded) answer

Comment: I would use the INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

May be you can define a Flag property and Enable,disable button while its Busy

```
 public bool IsBusyInstalling
    {
        get
        {
            return _isBusyInstalling;
        }
        private set
        {
            _isBusyInstalling = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsBusyInstalling");
        }
    }
```

and Simple style :

```
 <Style TargetType="Button">
       <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsBusyInstalling}" Value="True">
                   <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
               </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
```